# string and asm x86

Tags: string, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I'm new to asm and using string in.

1/I've got a string and I want to return the adress of the first caracter.
(I call the asm function in the C main).

I've tried :

```
movl  $str, %eax
```

According to me, it returns the string.

With  `movl  $(str), %eax` it returns the adress of the first caracter of the string ?
If I want to return the adress of the second character in the string, I don't understand how I can do that in asm.

I diplay result in the C program like that :

```
printf("string : %s, adress : %d\n", function_asm(), function_asm()).
```

It returns me "string : programmation, adress : 134520852"
I think that "134520852" is not an adress and there is something I don't understand.

2/I've seen there are `%edi`, `%esi` and functions for string but I can't find a good (easy) tutorial using that. I've just understand that %edi is for index source and %esi for index destination...do you know some links about it ?

thanks in advance !
:-)

Comment: What makes you think "that `134520852` is not an address"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how to get the address of the first character of a string into `eax`, the address of the second charcter can be obtained with a simple `inc %eax` (increment eax register).

I'm not sure *why* you think `134520852` is not the address of your string, *especially* if that string is indeed `"programmation"` - that would be prrof that the return from `function_asm()` was okay. Perhaps you would be happier printing it as a pointer, with `%p`.

And you're basically correct about `%edi` and `%esi` though you have them the wrong way around. `%esi` is the *source* one and `%edi` is the *destination* one.